# How to attach the particle system to the collider Or how to move the particle system with the character

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Does somebody have any idea how to attach particle system to the collider in the script? 
I have my character and I want to have blood particle system on the position of the tap on the head.  I have managed to do this with the code below but now I need to move it together with the collider(with the character). Because when I move my character(I use LeanTouch script for this) the blood is left where it was created on the scene.
The code I use, it is on the Camera:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ActionOnTapOrClick : MonoBehaviour {

    public ParticleSystem blood;

    private void Update()
    {

        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Ray toTouch = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit rhInfo;
            bool didHit = Physics.Raycast(toTouch, out rhInfo);
            if(didHit && rhInfo.collider != null )
            {
                Debug.Log("You've tapped on the " + rhInfo.collider.name);
                blood.transform.position = rhInfo.point;
                Instantiate(blood, rhInfo.point, transform.rotation);
            }
            else { Debug.Log("You need to tap on the head!"); }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You must set your particle parent to your collider. First check your collision position, then instantiate it on that coordinate with parent set to collider.

Comment: Also you can get your collision normal to set your particle rotation.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it right. All you need to do is to add your blood object as a child, so you can do something like this :
 `var ps = Instantiate(blood, rhInfo.point, transform.rotation); ps.transform.parent = transform;`
So check out [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-parent.html) and [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html) depending on your Unity version

Answer (score 1):

You should put in as a child object. This should work.

```
Instantiate(blood, rhInfo.point, transform.rotation, rhInfo.point.transform);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must attach the particle to the character object